# When I include a shared library, my executable is looking for two versions of it

Tags: c++, build, armadillo, mlpack

When I make my program with `-larmadillo`, I get an executable which wants two versions of it:

```
$ ldd ./a.out | grep armadillo 
$ libarmadillo.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarmadillo.so.7 (0x00007fd5e29a0000)
$ libarmadillo.so.4 => not found
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? This isn't making any sense to me!

Background: I initially installed libarmadillo via `sudo apt-get install libarmadillo-dev`, then I realised I needed to build it with a specific parameter (64 bit words enabled), so I uninstalled it via `sudo apt-get remove libarmadillo-dev` then downloaded the latest version, configured and make/make installed it. Presumably I only have one version of libarmadillo on my system - I do not see any old libraries in the usual places.

Thanks

EDIT:

My Makefile is:

```
CC= g++
CFLAGS= -Lcontrib/armadillo-7.400.1 -L/usr/include -Lcontrib/mlpack-2.0.1/build/lib -fpermissive -std=c++11 -O0 -g -Wall
LDFLAGS= -lmlpack -larmadillo
```

The verbose output of ldd is interesting, I think?

```
$ ldd -v ./a.out | grep armadillo 
$ libarmadillo.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarmadillo.so.7 (0x00007fd5e29a0000)
$ libarmadillo.so.4 => not found
$ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarmadillo.so.7:
```

The latter section (which lists dependences for libarmadillo.so.7) is:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarmadillo.so.7:
    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

There is no mention of the 'missing' libarmadillo.so.4 in the verbose output, which I find quite strange.

Comment: How was `a.out` build? What is in your makefile and/or configuration file(s)?

Comment: The objects are compiled with: `CFLAGS= -Lcontrib/armadillo-7.400.1 -L/usr/include -fpermissive -std=c++  11 -O0 -g -Wall` and `LFLAGS= -larmadillo`, using g++. I've attached the verbose output of ldd to the question also...

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out, but the results aren't particularly comforting.

I reinstalled `mlpack` which has a dependency into `libarmadillo`, and then rebuilt, and the requirement for `libarmadillo.so.4` is gone.

The process that I think happened is I:

- Installed old version of `libarmadillo`
- Installed `libmlpack` configured with old version
- Realised I needed a newer version of `libarmadillo`, so uninstalled old `libarmadillo` and installed a new one.
- Rebuilt mlpack using cmake / make **but did not `make install`**
- Made my executable
- Now have an executable which is is pointing to `mlpack` which requires the old `libarmadillo`, but it also points to the new `libarmadillo`

Once I `make install` the rebuilt `mlpack`, my problems go away. I am surprised that the verbose output of `ldd` didn't flag any reason as to **why** it was looking for `libarmadillo.so.4` (namely that there was a dependency from `libmlpack` on the old library) - should `ldd` be able to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes linux creates many symbolic link of one dynamic library. I don't know why but no matter as there is no inconvenient for that.  So, you can just create a new symbolic link like this : ln -s path_to_my_so_lib/my_lib.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarmadillo.so.4